# iText vs 4 layers values on top of each other

Tags: itext, pdfstamper

I am generating the creation of a PDF using values from an XML file.  The file is being created properly.  The problem I'm having is a bunch of values are being put into the same field.  I have commented out all the PDFStamper SetValue statements and brought them back one by one no matter how many lines are execute values are being duplicated in the last row.

I wanted to add an image to show what it looks like, but I keep getting errors about the "Body is missing".... Isn't this the body?

Comment: Please share enough code to reproduce the issue. What you describe is not normally observed, so most likely your code has a bug.

Comment: It's a 2-page PDF containing a form with many rows, so there are quite a few lines of code.  I decided to add one more row to the PDF with a Field that would not be populated by code.  After several tests, I learned that no matter how many rows were added to the PDF all the values would be dumped into that last row as well as where the values were set by code.

Comment: Do you use different names for the fields in the different rows?

Comment: yes, I do see different field names.  I think I will complete filling in the PDF, add a page just before the last row, and then delete the last page at the end.  It's not ideal... I really hate when I don't know why something is happening.  I can't spend days figuring out something that might be a bug in iText.

Comment: As mentioned before, what you describe is not normally seen in itext generated pdfs, so I assume a bug in your code which your work- around only would cover, not fix. Also possible would be a bug in itext seldom triggered. So probably consider cutting down your code tip make it sensibly shareable. If in the process the issue vanished, the problem code likely is in the removed lines.